# How to fix error cannot find module @microsoft/sp-build-web.When trying the sp-dev-ebpart samples

Tags: web-part, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, npm

I have been trying to build the https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts

I have gone through the instructions and reinstalled and installed but no luck
I am now getting the error:

> Cannot find module @microsoft/sp-build-web

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here. This happens after running - `gulp build` or `gulp serve`.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

[image]

I get the above error when I run `npm install @microsoft/sp-build-web`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version of nodeJS you have? and did npm install @microsoft/sp-build-web complete successfully or it gives any error?

Comment: Node V 10 and yes it gave some error as in my original post

Answer (score 1):

`@microsoft/sp-build-web` should be installed when you run `npm install` the first time.

In `package.json`, this is referenced in the `devDependencies` section:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.4.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "@types/prop-types": "ts2.4",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1"
}
```

As to why this was not installed in your case, there seems to be an issue with this particular sample.

Reference: [Keep getting "Verification failed while extracting @microsoft/sp-polyfills@1.2.0"](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/1027).

To correct this, delete the file `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Getting there with some of the sample and thanks guys.I keep running npm as the error occurs and I go to package one sample. Also I think deleting the package-lock.json also did help alot